# WordPress Editor Shortcuts Removed as of 4.2

Tags: wordpress, keyboard-shortcuts

Has anyone noticed as of WordPress 4.2, you can no longer use certain shortcuts, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for an H3 (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> for Mac)? I guess this is for accessibility sake or something, but it's killing me.

Does anyone know a way around it? Any plugins that add these shortcuts back in or that enable one to create shortcuts in the editor? Or even a simple code snippet that can be added to the functions.php to enable these shortcuts?

I need solutions for both Mac and PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to install any plugin or adding code in the functions.php
just change your key combinations:
from
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd>
to 
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>key</kbd>

For Example: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> will apply Heading 3.

---

**EDIT** (by Joe—the asker):

Thanks to your answer Mani Khan, I experimented and discovered a similar combination for Macs:

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> (makes an Heading 3)

Comment: Sorry, I use a Mac. I forgot to include Mac equivalents in my question. I've edited it to reflect that now. Thanks though! Good solution for a PC user (I'm assuming that works).

Comment: Thank you both so much (and sorry for my lag). These solutions work and totally solved my problem. Cheers!